# Highlight row if any value in the row cells is changed only today

Tags: microsoft-excel, sharepoint-online

I have a shared sheet called **"Daily Status"**, people update their respective rows daily, I want to highlight row if it is not updated today.

For example below sheet, 2 out of 3 people updated their row, but **John** did not updated his status for the day, I want to highlight his row.

```
+──────────────+───────+────────────────+
| Description  | User  | Status         |
+──────────────+───────+────────────────+
| Task 1       | James | 20% Completed  | → Updated today
| Task 2       | John  | 10% Completed  | → Updated yesterday
| Task 3       | Jane  | 100% Completed | → Updated today
+──────────────+───────+────────────────+
```

***Important - When I open the same sheet tomorrow, all the rows should be highlighted, because the data was updated on the previous day, and when again someone fills in new data highlight should get removed.***

Currently, I right-click on the particular row and click **Show Changes** to view when was it updated.

I don't think it is possible with conditional formatting or formula, I may need a script for this.

Comment: Does the column with "Updated today" or "Updated yesterday" exist? Is it a text column or date column? If it doesn't exist, you can create a column that people will populate with the date when they make changes. Then you can have a conditional formatting that will compare the dates and highlights the row if the date is not today's.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio No, I want to do that without those columns, But I like your idea, If it's not possible without those columns then I will try this thanks.

Comment: I'd be tempted to do this with a hidden backing sheet that handles the "last modified" dates of all the cells on this sheet, or at least the important columns. Then VBA could be used to set the cells on that sheet and conditional formatting on the front sheet based on that date.